# Measure network traffic from website for a user

Tags: networking, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

I have a need to determine how much bandwidth my web site generates, preferably per user.

I was thinking perhaps get a managed switch that can throttle port speed and looking at some it seems to only allow 10/100/1000mbit settings. Is there anything custom? Am I on the wrong track, how do people gather such data?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if something like iftop helps your situation.